# Function not running in Chrome, but perfectelly well in IE and Firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web

I have a function which mission is to go into a web page and transforms the images to grayscale.
It work perfectely on IE and Firefox.
However, it does not run in Chrome: the images keep in color; they are not transformed to grayscale.

Anyone have any idea why it happens ?

```
<html>
<head>

<script>

function transf_images(){
  var theImages = document.getElementsByTagName("img");

  for (var i=0; i <theImages.length; i++){
    var newImage=new Image();

    /*
    * Store the current index as the new image's id
    * since the onload function is async
    */
    newImage.id = i;        
    newImage.onload=function(){

      // Retrieve the correct index
      var i = this.id;

      // Get width and height
      var theWidth = theImages[i].width;
      var theHeight = theImages[i].height;

      // create a temporary canvas to put the original image
      var tempCanvas=document.createElement("canvas");
      var tempCtx=tempCanvas.getContext("2d");

      // Set width and height of the canvas
      tempCanvas.width = theWidth;
      tempCanvas.height = theHeight;

      // Draw the original in a temporary canvas
      tempCtx.drawImage(this, 0, 0, theWidth, theHeight);

      // pull the entire image into an array of pixel data
      var imageData = tempCtx.getImageData(0, 0, theWidth, theHeight);


      // CHANGE OF THE PIXEL COLOR

     var aux = new Array(3);

         for (var y = 0; y < theHeight; y ++) {
           for (var x = 0; x < theWidth; x ++) {
                 offset = ((y*(theWidth*4)) + (x*4));

                 aux[0] = imageData.data[offset + 0];
                 aux[1] = imageData.data[offset + 1];
                 aux[2] = imageData.data[offset + 2];

                 var gray =  (aux[0]+aux[1]+aux[2])/3;

                imageData.data[offset + 0] = Math.round(gray);
                imageData.data[offset + 1] = Math.round(gray);
                imageData.data[offset + 2] = Math.round(gray);
                imageData.data[offset + 3] = imageData.data[offset + 3]; 
           } //for
         } //for
         // final of the CHANGE OF THE PIXEL COLOR

      // put the altered data back on the canvas  
      tempCtx.putImageData(imageData,0,0);

      // Set the original image
      theImages[i].src = tempCanvas.toDataURL();

    }    // newImage.onload
    newImage.src = theImages[i].src;    

  }  //for  loop - for the image array
}  //function
</script>

</head>

<body onLoad="transf_images();">
    <p>First Image</p>
    <img src="imagens_250x180/rosa.jpg" name="image0" width=250 height=180 ><br/>
    <p>Second Image</p>
    <img src="imagens_250x180/ricardina.jpg" name="image1" width=250 height=180 >
     <p>Third Image</p>
    <img src="imagens_250x180/manaus.jpg" name="image1" width=250 height=180 >
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there any console error output?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use css filters?

```
img {  
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(1); /* Webkit */  
    filter: gray; /* IE6-9 */  
    filter: grayscale(1); /* W3C */  
}
```

Also see to this [demo](http://demo.hongkiat.com/grayscale-web-image/)

Comment: I cannot. What I real want to do is to adapt the images for colorblind people. In the sample above presented, I changed the way I change each pixel, in order to simplify. 
Thanks

Comment: @user3059287 If you have any question or you need advice, provide demo )) I can help)

Comment: I can send to you the HTML file and the 3 images in a ziped file, by e-mail, if you consider it convenient.
Anyway, the code is all here. Only the 3 images are not.

Answer (score 0):

I AM THE AUTHOR OF THE QUESTION

I tried other sugestions, but none solved.

Then, I did put the code online (in a server) and it worked.
Now, it works perfectelly, both in Chrome.

Thanks for the sugestions